# How to add Dynamic Title to application - VueJS

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router

I have added the below routing mechanism

```
{
    path: '/home',
    meta: { title : 'Welcome Back, ' + profile.userName + ' – Dashboard | A Company' },
    name: 'home',
    component: () => import('@/views/Home.vue'),
},
```

I need to add the title for every page. But I don't see the above reflected when I run the application. So I have the below in `**Vue.app**`

```
watch: {
    '$route' (to, from) {
        document.title = to.meta.title || 'A Company'
    }
},
```

Now, the title loads. But it is not able to pick the `profile.username` once the API call is completed.

Is it possible to change the title once the API returns the data?

Comment: I think it is impossible in pure vue.js but you can use nuxt.js which can solve your problem. You can read more about this [here](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-head/)

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to change the title once the API returns the data?

Yes, but I don't know all of your code so I can't write *exactly* something you can just copy and paste, but you can adjust it until it works.

The main change would be to make `meta.title` a function

```
{
  path: '/home',
  meta: {
    title: async function() {
      var userName = await getUsernameFromWhereverYoureGettingItFrom()
      return `Welcome Back, ${username} – Dashboard | A Company`
    }
  },
  name: 'home',
  component: () =>
    import ('@/views/Home.vue'),
},
```

Then call that function

```
watch: {
    '$route': async (to, from) {
        document.title = to.meta.title ? await to.meta.title() : 'A Company'
    }
},
```

Comment: I see you are making an API call in routes. But for me routes is different and the APIs are different